# Does autovaccum wake up in slave?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I cannot find the answer to question what I wrote in the title. Postgres automatically wake vacuum by autovacuum, but when it's slave does slave wake up autovacuum process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Vacuum only runs on the master.  The results of vacuuming are WAL logged and so replicated through to the slave via the normal WAL replay mechanism.